# Is it safe to pass pointers to data members to base class constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, language-lawyer

Is it safe to pass pointers to data members to base class constructor? i.e., is the memory layout of the derived class data members, at least, already set before the base class constructor is called, even if the data members are not yet initialized?

Obviously, dereferencing the pointers must only be done after construction has completed, and the objects pointed to are already valid. But the question is if it's guaranteed that the pointers received by the base class constructor would actually still point to their objects once construction of the derived object has completed.

The motivation is providing some functionality in the base class, for example iterating over the pointers-to-objects provided at construction and do something for each at a later time.

It's possible to just provide a setter accessible to the derived class, but I'm curious if it's also safe to provide the pointers at construction time.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct Base {
   Base(std::initializer_list<int*> ptrs = {}) : ptrs_(ptrs) {}
   std::vector<int*> ptrs_;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived() : Base{{&a_,&b_,&c_}} {}
    int a_=1, b_=2, c_=3;
};

int main()
{
    Derived obj;
    for (auto* ptr : obj.ptrs_) { std::cout << *ptr << '\n'; }
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/rDJw0UU8KcWckLlo

Comment: Note: please use parentheses to initialize `ptrs_`. It's a pretty sharp edge to use `{}` to initialize types that have `initializer_list` constructors when you're not specifically using that functionality.

Comment: @Barry done, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Your code is fine.** But note that the behaviour on *dereferencing* the pointers in the base class constructor would be undefined.

You are allowed to pass a *pointer* or *reference* to a member variable to a base class constructor, but you must not actually access the object in that base class constructor.

Comment: well I still have the first version in my mind, I guess with the edits the answer is just fine :)

Comment: I've added an even more explicit clarifying paragraph to the question.

Comment: Any relevant standard references?

Comment: @Danra - So long as you guarantee the pointers are dereferenced only after the members are initialized, you are all set. It's not uncommon to "cheat" and obtain a reference to an object before the object is *there*. Here's the standard ref making it kosher: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6

Comment: @StoryTeller: Be an angel and wack in an answer. I'll up it.

Comment: I'm all capped out :) Besides, you said it better that my coffee deprived mind is capable to at the moment ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller: I'll up it tomorrow ;-)